# CheckBox in ListView, setVisibility using SimpleCursorAdapter and CursorLoader

Tags: android, checkbox, simplecursoradapter, android-cursorloader

Please, help me to find a solution how to set my checkboxes visible when I click on menu item "delete" and set invisible when I press "confirm" or "cancel". 
I use SimpleCursorAdapter, cuz listview is filled from database with cursor loader...
here is my code:

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

    final String LOG = "phonebookLogs";

    private static final int LOADER_ID = 1;

    Intent intentAddContact;
    ListView lvMain;
    CheckBox cbxList;
    MenuItem addContact, deleteContact, settings, expimp, confirmDelete, cancelDelete;

    DB mDB;
    SimpleCursorAdapter scAdapter;  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //find ListView
        lvMain = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvMain);

        //calling for creating adapter
        onCreateAdapter();

    }

    public void onCreateAdapter(){

        String[] from = new String[] { DB.COL_LINK, DB.COL_SURNAME, DB.COL_NAME };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.ivPhoto, R.id.tvSurname, R.id.tvName, };
        if(to[0] == 0){
            to[0] = R.drawable.default_contact;
        }

        scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, null, from, to, 0);
        lvMain.setAdapter(scAdapter);

        // loader for reading data
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
    }   

    public void deleteRecord(){
        //when MenuItem "Delete" is clicked
        addContact.setVisible(false);
        deleteContact.setVisible(false);
        settings.setVisible(false);
        expimp.setVisible(false);
        confirmDelete.setVisible(true);
        cancelDelete.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void onCancelDeleteRecord(){
        ////when MenuItem "cancel" is clicked
        addContact.setVisible(true);
        deleteContact.setVisible(true);
        settings.setVisible(true);
        expimp.setVisible(true);
        confirmDelete.setVisible(false);
        cancelDelete.setVisible(false);

    }

    public void confirmDeleteRecord(){
        ////when MenuItem "confirm" is clicked
        addContact.setVisible(true);
        deleteContact.setVisible(true);
        settings.setVisible(true);
        expimp.setVisible(true);
        confirmDelete.setVisible(false);
        cancelDelete.setVisible(false);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        //find all MenuItems
        addContact = menu.findItem(R.id.addContact);
        deleteContact = menu.findItem(R.id.deleteContact);
        settings = menu.findItem(R.id.settings);
        expimp = menu.findItem(R.id.expimp);
        confirmDelete = menu.findItem(R.id.confirmDelete);
        cancelDelete = menu.findItem(R.id.cancelDelete);    

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.addContact:
            intentAddContact = new Intent(this, NewContact.class);
            startActivity(intentAddContact);
            break;
        case R.id.deleteContact:
            deleteRecord();
            break;
        case R.id.settings:

            break;
        case R.id.expimp:

            break;
        case R.id.confirmDelete:
            confirmDeleteRecord();
            break;
        case R.id.cancelDelete:
            onCancelDeleteRecord();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bndl) {
        return new MyCursorLoader(this, mDB);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        scAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        scAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

}
```

DB.class and CursorLoader.class are fine, simple query and loading.
and my XML-file for ListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivPhoto"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/imageWidth"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/imageHeight"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:contentDescription="@string/photoDescription"
                android:src="@drawable/default_contact" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="@dimen/textSize" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSurname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="@dimen/textSize" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbxList"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have read a lot already, but how to realize it without creating my own adapter still can't get...
will be thanksfull to any help in finding solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your checkbox as visible with: `cbxlist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

And if you want it completely gone, use (ie make it look as if it was never added): `cbxlist.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

If you want it to be just invisible, but still occupy the same space: `cbxlist.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

Edit:

```
for(int i = 0; i < lvMain.getChildCount(); i++) {

      lvMain.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.cbxList).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

That should set all of your checkbox's to visible. Similarly call for `View.INVISIBLE` when required.

Comment: no, not MenuItem set invisible, but checkbox, which inside of ListView... I can't just call CheckBox cbxList = (CheckBox)findViewById (R.id.cbxList); ... will be a nullPointerException...

Comment: I'm sorry can you clarify, what do you want to set as visible/invisible? Adding a screenshot of your layout to your question might help.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't add, because of low reputation like it said...
when I click on MenuItem"delete" must appear checkboxes to all fields in listview... they are in xml-file, but default, they are invisible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change visibility of each checkbox in your listview (assuming your XML is your list row view), you need to create your custom adapter and override getView method.

In there, you will do the following:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    cBox = (CheckBox ) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbxList);
    cBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it is inside of listview... nullpointerexception is given and it is right. I need to get it somehow without creating my own adapter..

Comment: this way how can I set adapter in MainActivity, because I use CursorLoader so I used not custom adaper, but SimpleCursorAdapter... as far as I know they don't match to each other... CursorLoader will return NullPoiEx that way((